# Remove BackgroundView from UITargetedPreview in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm trying to remove the background view for my `UITargetPreview`. I made the background color clear, however, you can still see the frame of the background.

This is what it currently looks like:

[image]

I currently have a view that has the text container and the image inside of it and that's what I use as the view for the `UITargetedPreview`.

Is there a way to only show the image and the text and not the background frame?

Comment: It should be possible if you change the target preview frame to only include the message and not the user icon.

Comment: Can you share a mockup of the desired result? Do you want the shadow to only sit behind the image? Also, think about sending your image followed by another message that is the text. Like how an iMessage works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a tricky method to hide the shadow and to do that you should find a view with `_UIPlatterSoftShadowView` class name in the view hierarchy and then hide it.

```swift
func viewByClassName(view: UIView, className: String) -> UIView? {
    let name = NSStringFromClass(type(of: view))
    if name == className {
        return view
    }
    else {
        for subview in view.subviews {
            if let view = viewByClassName(view: subview, className: className) {
                return view
            }
        }
    }
    return nil
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayContextMenu configuration: UIContextMenuConfiguration, animator: UIContextMenuInteractionAnimating?) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if let window = UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window! {
            if let view = self.viewByClassName(view: window, className: "_UIPlatterSoftShadowView") {
                view.isHidden = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE: It's not documented internal class and can be changed anytime further but it works now on both ios 13/14.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried subclassing the UIView as a UIControl?
I had a similar issue but in my case the view for UITargetedPreview was glitchy. However, changing the UIView to a UIControl fixed everything.

Comment: You don't need to code for this, just select the view you are using as the UITargetedPreview on the storyboard, and change the class to a UIControl

Answer (score 0):

try removing shadow of that background view.

Answer (score 0):

You need to study UIBezierPath() to outline the specific area you want to enclose before you present the target view.

After that, you shall assign the specific path to shadow path / visible path

```
let params = UIPreviewParameters()
        params.backgroundColor = .clear
        if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
            params.shadowPath = bubblePath
        } else {
            params.visiblePath = bubblePath
        }
```